# SqlException (0x80131904): Unable to open the physical file

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, web-config, connection

I just deployed my website on IIS and fixed the connection to database via (LocalDB).\IIS_DB in my Web.config file for the connection string.

These 2 links for what i said above,

[Using LocalDB with Full IIS, Part 1: User Profile](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/12/08/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile/),

[Using LocalDB with Full IIS, Part 2: Instance Ownership](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/12/08/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-2-instance-ownership/)

Everything works well

When i accessed the starting page which is set for Login.aspx, what i set in Default Document in IIS i could login with an account found from the database. But now when i accessed another page named AdminPanel.aspx i got this error down below..

[image: error]

I tried searching over stackoverflow to look for solutions but nothing seems to solve this error..

My web.config file from my publised website on IIS

[image: webconfig]

Appreciate any help please.. I'm guessing this is the last error before i complete my school project - Publishing WebSite onto IIS to allow other computer in my network to access my site.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your SQL DB, the `MDF` file that you are connecting is already present in DB server. Attach `MDF` file don't need the DB  created in DB server.

Check your `DB`  connection string.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply Mohan.. I just have to remove this "AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\FinancialHub.mdf"?

Comment: Not like that.First check your db.Attached MDF, containing tables or not.Then change the connection string based on your requirement.